# Installing Apache Spark on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, bigdata, installation, apache-spark

Is there any easier way to install Apache spark on windows 7 64 bit locally?

Comment: Easier than what?  What is your actual problem?

Comment: I am having problems in building spark on Windows 7 64 bit particularly with SBT.

Comment: Can you describe the build problems that you're seeing in more detail (maybe edit your question to include portions of the build log)?  Which version of Spark are you building?  Are you building it using powershell / cmd.exe or Cygwin

Answer (score 1):

Install windows version of sbt from their site, there is msi installer.
Increase max memory for sbt jvm - create system variable SBT_OPTS = -Xmx512M
You may have some proxy/firewall issues if packages download fails
Run cmd as admin (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
Install Spark to a folder path without spaces otherwise spark-shell.cmd fails

If it doesn;t help provide error messages or better describe problem.

Answer (score 1):

Building Spark with sbt installer was quite easy. You can try with the steps mentioned in the following blog.

[How to run Apache Spark on Windows7](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)

Hope you'll be able to do it without error.